# Negate a propositional Function

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Unsure if negation is correct

$$\exists r\forall w G(w) \wedge C(r)$$
$\forall r$ $\exists w$ $\neg$G(w) $\vee$ $\neg C(r)$

Comment: I think the quickest way would just be $\not \exists j \forall p F(p) \land B(j)$

Comment: maybe, but I have to use these steps. implication to conjunction or morgans laws,etc. I just want to validate what I got is right

Comment: Last line looks fine. Only one moment: in first half, possibly, is more good to use some other letter in place of $j$, because really it is not there, is bounded,  but is free in second half $B(j)$.

Comment: Please try to formalize the statement, and improve the layout of your equations.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Quibbles: it's a formula not an "equation". Also, I and others wouldn't call it a "propositional function": it's a first-order formula that uses quantifiers and individual variables and not just propositional variables and connectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself, is the following possible: $$(\exists j \forall p F(p) \land B(j)) \land (\forall j \exists p \neg F(p) \land B(j))$$ It isn't. If the exists a $j$ for all $p$'s, that satisfies a condition, then there cannot exist a $p$ for all $j$'s that doesn't satisfy the condition. Thus, they are each other's negation, and you're correct.